# Ruby on Rails autosave associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, autosave

I have three associated classes in Rails v. 3.2.15, with Ruby 2.1.1, and a join-table class between two of them:

```
class Grandarent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents, autosave: true
end

class Parent
  belongs_to :grandparent
  has_many :children, :through => :parent_children, autosave: true
end

class ParentChild
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :child
end

class Child
  has_many :parent_children
  has_many :parents, :through => :parent_children
end
```

If I execute the following, then changes to child are not saved:

```
gp = Grandparent.find(1)
gp.parents.first.children.first.first_name = "Bob"
gp.save
gp.parents.first.children.first.first_name  ## -> Whatever name was to begin with (i.e. NOT Bob)
```

But if I force Rails to evaluate and return data from each connection, then the save is successful

```
gp = Grandparent.find(1)
gp.parents
gp.parents.first
gp.parents.first.children
gp.parents.first.children.first
gp.parents.first.children.first.first_name = "Bob"
gp.save
gp.parents.first.children.first.first_name  ## -> "Bob"
```

If I subsequently execute gp = Grandparent.find(1) again, then I've reset the whole thing, and have to force the evaluation of associations again.

Is this intentional behavior, or have I done something wrong?  Do I need to hang an autosave on the join table connections as well as (or instead of) the has_many :through connection?

From the documentation, I see that "loaded" members will be saved.  Is this what is necessary to load them?  Can someone define exactly what "loaded" is, and how to achieve that state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because `gp.parents` caches the `parents` into a results `Array`, then `parents.first` is actually calling `Array.first`. However, `gp.parents.first` performs a query with `LIMIT 1` every time, and so returns a new object every time.

You can confirm like so:

```
gp.parents.first.object_id # performs new query (LIMIT 1)
=> 1

gp.parents.first.object_id # performs new query (LIMIT 1)
=> 2

gp.parents                 # performs and caches query for parents
gp.parents.first.object_id # returns first result from parents array
=> 1

gp.parents.first.object_id # returns first result from parents array
=> 1
```

You can chain an update with your query like so:

`gp.parents.first.children.first.update_attributes(first_name: "Bob")`

Comment: Thanks so much.  That's ... weird.  The takeaway I'm getting is not to use .first, .last, etc. in production code.  It's not going to be realistic to search through our entire app, replacing property set by an equal sign with update_attributes(), I fear.  

Is there something I should have done differently that would have avoided this?  Is it best practice to use update_attributes instead of object.property = value, or to avoid relying on autosave altogether?  I guess I just want to know the best way to keep this from being a problem in the future.

Comment: Also, is it safe to loop over the children of a parent, updating each one, then save the parent?

Comment: @whognu it's difficult to say how to avoid this in the future other than being aware of when you're dealing with cached results, or a new result set every time. `object.property =` is fine, as is using `first/last`. But that will then expect `object.save` to persist. It will only save as an association if it belongs to an array of children that are already loaded.

Comment: @whognu reason is when you perform `gp.parents.first` on its own it performs a query and returns the first object. But then if you perform `gp.parents` it will perform a whole new query, and, as such, calling `gp.parents.save` will only save changes on that *new* result set. What you're doing in that case is loading `gp.parents` and saving straight away on an unchanged result set. It has no knowledge of `gp.parents.first`.